# How to use webpack 4 JSON tree-shaking feature with keys containing the character "-"?

Tags: javascript, json, webpack

I would like to use [webpack 4's JSON tree-shaking feature](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/pull/6184) but I am hitting a roadblock.

This is some working code:

```
import { accessibility_16 } from '@collab-ui/icons/data/iconsData.json';

console.log("accessibility_16:", accessibility_16);
```

[`iconsData.json`](https://github.com/collab-ui/collab-ui-icons/blob/master/data/iconsData.json) is a HUGE file, but thanks to `webpack` I only get the code related to `accessibility_16` in the final bundle (when using `webpack -p`). The issue is that some keys in the JSON file are not valid JavaScript identifiers, example: `arrow-circle-down_16`.

```
import { arrow-circle-down_16 } from '@collab-ui/icons/data/iconsData.json';
```

The code above is invalid.

How can I import `arrow-circle-down_16` **and** still benefit from JSON tree-shaking?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have found how to write code to do what I want thanks to this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6305) but I am not certain that it's future-proof:

```
import * as json from "@collab-ui/icons/data/iconsData.json";
const path = json["arrow-circle-down_16"];
console.log("arrow-circle-down_16:", path);
```

Comment: Well this will import the whole file won't it?